# I try to use layout_weight combination with layout_width or layout_height, but in vain

Tags: android

Many answers have point out: when we use layout_weight we shoule set the layout_height="0dp", if we set layout_height="fill_parent", the result not our expection. what  layout_height="fill_parent" have done in OnMeasure? who can explain it? 
I'm sorry. this is my first time asking question. the scene is below:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:background="#a00"
        android:text="r" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:background="#0a0"
        android:text="g" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#00a"
        android:text="b" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: now that depends upon your parent layout, if you have set LinearLayout's orientation to Vertical and if if you add view with height 0dip and weight then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Without any code, it's hard to help you, but I'll give it a shot.

First, `layout_weight` is an attribute that only works on a LinearLayout (and its subclasses). If you are using any other ViewGroup as the parent, it won't work.

Second, `layout_weight` is used to divide UNUSED space. After all the other children have been laid out, children with a layout_weight will take up the rest of the available space, based on the weights. This is why people often recommend giving a view `layout_height="0dp"` when using `layout_gravity`. This means it doesn't take up any space until after everything else is done. If you have a child filling it's parent, there isn't any space left to divide up.

Hopefully, this will help you understand how to use `layout_weight` better.

Comment: I'm sorry. this is my first time asking question. the scene is below:

Comment: another example is : `<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#f00"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#0f0"
        android:layout_weight="2"/>

</LinearLayout>`

Comment: you haven't really told us what you are trying to get. do you want all the children to be equal? do you want them to take up a percentage of the available space? what effect are you trying for?

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#a00"
    android:text="r" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#0a0"
    android:text="g" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#00a"
    android:text="b" />
```

Now here weight 1 will give them equal space, you can modify it according to your requirements